# Event in subscriber not firing

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I can't seem to figure out why an event is not firing.

In `ProviderEvenServiceProvider`

```php
protected $subscribe = [
  'App\Listeners\ProductEventSubscriber',
];
```

In `Listeners\ProductEventSubscriber`

```php
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Events\ConversionHasBeenCompleted;


public function mediaConversionHasBeenCompleted($event)
{
    Log::info('Hi');
}


public function subscribe($events)
{
    return [
        ConversionHasBeenCompleted::class => [
            [ProductEventSubscriber::class, 'mediaConversionHasBeenCompleted'],
        ],
    ];
}
```

I've ran `php artisan optimize:clear` and restarted horizon. I can see the event being processed and successfully being completed. The method `mediaConversionHasBeenCompleted` is not fired however. What could I be missing?

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: The latest, 8.16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I was using the `ConversionHasBeenCompleted` event, while I had to use the `ResponsiveImagesGenerated` because I'm using the responsive images option. This event is not documented so I'll ping the Spatie team.

Comment: Great! This saved me a lot of hours